# Silverlight application ria service list files in service side

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, server-side, file-listing

Having a silverlight application, intended to implement backup restore mechanism for the end user.

I have to get list of files in a specific directory resided in **WebSite** project via **ria services**.

By using  which object I will be able to list files in specific directory of **WebSite** project.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Why downvoted ? This question is answered nowhere ! It may help someone in the future.

Comment: It was likely down voted because this is simply doing something that websites should always avoid.  You need to protect the implementation of your website from threats.  Listing all the files on your site is like laying down the welcome mat and opening the door.

Comment: It will not list all files on the server. It will only show the saved backup files. The security of the site is another issue which can be discussed in its time but it is not a good excuse to not to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is some kind of hack. I was inspired by the method that I have used to send client IP address to the service.

In default.aspx add this param to your silverlight object :

```
<param name="initParams" value="clientIP=<%=Request.UserHostAddress%>,serverPath=<%=Server.MapPath(".")%>" />
```

And in silverlight application :

```
    public string ClientIP=string.Empty;
    public string ServerPath = string.Empty;


    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootVisual = new MainPage();

        try
        {
            ClientIP = e.InitParams["clientIP"].ToString();
            ServerPath = e.InitParams["serverPath"].ToString();
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
    }
```

Consider that I sent client ip to the xap file for logging issues. You can omit it if you care.

and in Silverlight application call service method in this way :

```
 ser.GetFileList(((App)(App.Current)).ServerPath, FilesListReceived, null);
```

And the service side :

```
 public List<string> GetFileList(string baseDirectory)
 {
        var result = new List<BRFile>();

        var files =Directory.EnumerateFiles(  baseDirectory + "\\DBBackup" );

        ....
 }
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Directory class to enumerate files on the server. Adding a method to your domain service to return the list of file names to the Silverlight client should be fairly trivial after that.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I knew this object. How can I understand the absolute path of WebSite project to pass it to this class ?

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() will probably suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately the result was : ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0"" which is not the service directory.